# How can I use an X.509 certificate with private key from the android keychain in C#/Xamarin?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-keystore

I'm building a Xamarin app that should load X.509 certificates and RSA public keys from the Android keychain. I want to convert them to an instance of *X509Certificate2* (*System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2*), but I don't really know how to do this.

I was able to access both certificate chain (*java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]*) and private key (*java.security.IPrivateKey*), but I can't combine them to a *X509Certificate2*. I found [this](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/KeyChain-API-on-Android-4-1-and-client-certificate-authentication-td5712844.html) old thread, where the author had a similar problem, but there wasn't really a solution for his problem.

This is the code used by him (doesn't work anymore since Android 4.1. Also, I don't know which PKCS8 class he used, as *Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS8* is not public):

```
X509Certificate[] certChain = KeyChain.GetCertificateChain(ctx, Alias);
IPrivateKey privKey = KeyChain.GetPrivateKey(ctx, Alias);

KeyStore pkcs12KeyStore = KeyStore.GetInstance("PKCS12");
pkcs12KeyStore.Load(null, null);
pkcs12KeyStore.SetKeyEntry(Alias, privKey, null, certChain);

X509Certificate javaCertificate = (X509Certificate) pkcs12KeyStore.GetCertificate(Alias);

PKCS8.PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = new PKCS8.PrivateKeyInfo(privKey.GetEncoded());
RSA privatekeyRsa = PKCS8.PrivateKeyInfo.DecodeRSA(privateKeyInfo.PrivateKey);

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(javaCertificate.GetEncoded());
certificate.PrivateKey = privatekeyRsa;
```

Starting in Android 4.1, *privKey.GetEncoded()* returns *null*, so I can't use this way and therefore don't know how to get the private key into *certificate*.

So, the question is: How can I create a X509Certificate2 with the KeyChain API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.
It's because the private key is stored in hardware and from Android 4.1, inaccessible to your app, that's why it returns null.
[Here's an article](https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0001.html) in case you want to read about it more.

Comment: Damn it. I almost expected this, but thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Did you find a solution to use the private key?

Comment: @Angelru as I mentioned, you can't do it anymore.